# Creating object dynamically using Object.create()

Tags: javascript

I have a scenario, where I need to create objects dynamically.

In my example, an object `meta` contains the name for the constructor function to be used during initialization `Object.create()`.

At the moment using the following code, I am able to create the objects dynamically but the property `name` is not defined.

I need that property on the result;

What is wrong in my script? Do you know a better way to achieve the same result?

```js
      (function () {
            var costructors = {
                A: function () {
                    this.name = 'A';
                    console.log(this.name);
                },
                B: function () {
                    this.name = 'B';
                    console.log(this.name);
                },
                C: function () {
                    this.name = 'C';
                    console.log(this.name);
                }
            },
            meta = {
                A: true,
                B: true,
                C: true,
            },
            result = [];
            function createObjs() {
                Object.keys(meta).forEach(function (type) {
                    var obj = Object.create(costructors[type].prototype);
                    result.push(obj);
                }.bind(this));
            }
            createObjs.call(this);
            console.log(result);
        })();
```

Comment: Why the `.bind(this)` on the anonymous function of `.forEach()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined a prototype for any of the constructors, so you're not creating the name in your instances, since you're creating an object from their prototype, not from their constructor. Try

```
Object.create(constructors[type])
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative without using `Object.create` would be:

```
var obj = new costructors[type]();
```

instead of:

```
var obj = Object.create(costructors[type].prototype);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `Object.create` does not call the constructor function, but only creates a new object from the given prototype. Any member variables can be provided via a property object:

```
var obj = Object.create(
  constructors[type].prototype,
  { 'name' : { value: 'A', writable: true}}
);
```